# scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh returns different eigenvalues for the same matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, eigenvalue

## Problem summary

I want to calculate the smallest eigenvalue (algebraic value) of a matrix. The matrix comes from an op4 file that I read using the [pyNastran](https://github.com/SteveDoyle2/pyNastran) library. Following [these instructions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/arpack.html), I am trying to calculate the smallest eigevanlue using the `scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh` function with shift-invert mode. In order to check that the computation is correct, I compare the result of `eigsh` with the result of `numpy.linalg.eigvals`. What I observe is quite puzzling: if I simply apply `eigsh` to the matrix, the calculated eigenvalue is wrong, if I save the matrix to a csv file and then I load it back into a `numpy` array the eigenvalue is correct. What is even more baffling is that `numpy.array_equal` returns `True` when I compare the two matrices. How is it possible that `eigsh` returns two different results for the same matrix?

## Code

```
from pyNastran.op4.op4 import read_op4
from scipy.sparse.linalg import eigsh
import numpy as np
op4 = read_op4('kllrh.op4')
matrix_name = 'KLLRH'
kllrh_matrix = op4[matrix_name][1][-1]
reference_max_eigenvalue = np.max(np.linalg.eigvals(kllrh_matrix))
reference_min_eigenvalue = np.min(np.linalg.eigvals(kllrh_matrix))
eigsh_min_eigenvalue = eigsh(kllrh_matrix, 1, sigma=0, which='LM', return_eigenvectors=False)
np.savetxt('kllrh.csv', kllrh_matrix, delimiter=',')
kllrh_matrix_reloaded = np.loadtxt('kllrh.csv', delimiter=",")
reloaded_eigsh_min_eigenvalue = eigsh(kllrh_matrix_reloaded, 1, sigma=0, which='LM', return_eigenvectors=False)
print(reference_min_eigenvalue)
print(eigsh_min_eigenvalue)
print(reloaded_eigsh_min_eigenvalue)
print(np.array_equal(kllrh_matrix, kllrh_matrix_reloaded))
print(type(kllrh_matrix))
print(type(kllrh_matrix_reloaded))
print(reference_max_eigenvalue)
```

This returns the following:

```
-0.0028387385
[0.05363945]
[-0.00283876]
True
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
6502976000.0
```

Please find the `kllrh.op4` file [here](https://uob-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/qa21944_bristol_ac_uk/ES3FXpZGImxAtBV1u58bkJsB0jw3J8wVEAM9zsa_28R4lA?e=rcJxn0).

Comment: What is the `type` of `kllrh_matrix ` and `kllrh_matrix_reloaded ` ?  I get the feeling one is sparse (some `scipy.sparse` formulation) and the other is dense (an `np.ndarray`)  Also, can you include the max eigenvalues?  I have a feeling you have a very ill-conditioned matrix (`max_eig >> min_eig`) which amplify small numerical differences due to method.

Comment: I have edited the questions adding the requested info. Yes the matrix is ill-conditioned, but the `type` is the same. And `numpy.array_equal` always returns `True`, so the application of the same operation should return the same result, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although `np.array_equal` says that `kllrh_matrix` and `kllrh_matrix_reloaded` are equal, they are of different `dtype`s (`float32` vs `float64`).

If you do

```
kllrh_matrix = op4[matrix_name][1][-1].astype('float64')
```

everything is correct:

```
-0.0028387384680708
[-0.00283876]
[-0.00283876]
True
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
6502976138.583383
```

As a better alternative, you can specify the `precision` when reading the op4 file:

```
op4 = read_op4('kllrh.op4', precision='double')
```

which will give you slightly other results:

```
0.004395871268066287
[0.00439589]
[0.00439589]
True
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
6502976180.582107
```

The default precision comes from the op4 file: in the example the matrix type is `1` (fourth number on first line of the file) which [results](https://github.com/SteveDoyle2/pyNastran/blob/14798312ac0419857ce030ee367f924b4924f9fd/pyNastran/op4/op4.py#L1874-L1876) in single precision (`float32`).